# Adobe Edge Animate - Document Ready events?

Tags: adobe-edge

With Adobe Edge Animate, I am trying to hide an object on page load. I will create a click event on another object which will toggle the first object to a visible state.

How do I hide an object/symbol on page load? According to https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/edgeanimate/api/old/0.1.7/EdgeAPI.0.1.7.html there is a compositionReady event, but I'm not sure how to apply this with the Edge interface. All I see is a list of events like "click, dblclick, mouseover," etc.

How do I create an event rather than choose an event from the list Edge supplies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get to composition ready, make sure you are on the main stage in your project (not within a symbol) and click on the {o} symbol to the left of the stage in the timeline panel.

The actions panel for the main stage should pop up and you will be able to select compositionReady from there.
:)